# selecting element a from table X which is most frequent in table Y SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

Table X

```
| ID |Name|
| -- | -- |
|101 | a  |
|102 | b  |
|103 | c  |
```

Table Y

```
| ID |T   |
| -- | -- |
|101 | t  |
|101 | s  |
|102 | t  |
|103 | t  |
|101 | t  |
|103 | t  |
```

I want **Name** of most frequent **ID**s in **Table Y** with **T='t'**

in this case it should return **a**,**b**

anyone can help me please?

Comment: Expected output should be a and c

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and window functions:

```
select x.name, y.cnt
from (select id, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from y
      where t = 't'
      group by id
     ) y join
     x
     on x.id = y.id
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks man, it worked but does it check the T='t'?

Comment: @MHRZD . .  .I *knew* I left something out.